# I’m trying to get a terminal output to be printed in Streamlit.But its not printed in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

[here in terminal the url is coming but in right side see its not printed in streamlit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdJkF.png)[this is the function i have used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE2Td.png)

this is the full code i have used :

```
 from googlesearch import search

 import streamlit as st



 def get_founder(self, startup_name):
   
    query = f"founder of {startup_name}?"
    
    search_results = list(search(query))
   
    for result in search_results:
        if result in result.lower():
            return result
        return "Founder name not found"


  founder = startup_info.get_founder(startups)

  st.write(founder);
```

it gives the output url in terminal but not in streamlit

please resolve the issue

Comment: Please share a runnable code snippet so we can reproduce the issue. Learn more about creating a minimal reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: problem got solved, thank you